# How do Struts tag attributes work?

Tags: attributes, struts

In this code:

```
<html:text property="txtItem5" disabled="disTxtItem5">
```

I can see that "txtItem5" comes from a getTxtItem5() in the ActionForm, but searching the project for other substrings of "disTxtItem5" seemingly reveals nothing remotely related, though clearly somehow the framework is pulling a boolean from this string, which clearly means that it's more complicated than my current understanding.

Could someone give a good explanation of how these expressions are evaluated, or point me in the direction of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** In my original response (see below) I said that Struts manages the conversion, but I was wrong. I didn’t remember exactly what was going so I pulled out Struts’s sources and took a look. It turns out that the conversion is made by the server. The JSP is converted to a servlet before execution and it is here that false is used for non boolean values.

For example, I used the following tag:

```
<html:text property="nr" disabled="BlaBla" />
```

Which was translated to the following html (no disabled):

```
<input type="text" name="nr" value="123">
```

This happened in the servlet. Here is what my servlet contains for the above tag:

```
//  html:text
    org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextTag _jspx_th_html_005ftext_005f0 = (org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextTag) _005fjspx_005ftagPool_005fhtml_005ftext_005fproperty_005fdisabled_005fnobody.get(org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextTag.class);
    _jspx_th_html_005ftext_005f0.setPageContext(_jspx_page_context);
    _jspx_th_html_005ftext_005f0.setParent((javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) _jspx_th_html_005fform_005f0);
    _jspx_th_html_005ftext_005f0.setProperty("nr");
    _jspx_th_html_005ftext_005f0.setDisabled(false);
    int _jspx_eval_html_005ftext_005f0 = _jspx_th_html_005ftext_005f0.doStartTag();
```

As it can be seen, the disabled value is generated with false, directly. I did some more digging into the Jasper compiler (I used Tomcat) and I think that it is the org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil class that is responsible for the conversion, with the following code:

```
public static boolean booleanValue(String s) {
  boolean b = false;
  if (s != null) {
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
       b = true;
    } else {
       b = Boolean.valueOf(s).booleanValue();
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```

Since I inserted BlaBla in the disabled field this should fallback to `Boolean.valueOf(s).booleanValue();` which does the following:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
  return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

private static boolean toBoolean(String name) { 
  return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

This way, BlaBla results in false.

**ORIG:** *The following was my original response, but was incorrect. What I was describing was in fact what happens when request parameters are binded to the action form.*

The disabled attribute is of type boolean, so it should receive only values that map to a boolean. `disabled="disTxtItem5"` would throw a ConversionException because the text `disTxtItem5` does not map to a boolean.

Struts uses [CommonBeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to make conversions, so a BooleanConverter will be used, with code like the following:

```
String stringValue = value.toString();
if (stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("true") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("on") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
   return (Boolean.TRUE);
} else if (stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("no") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("n") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("false") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("off") ||
   stringValue.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
   return (Boolean.FALSE);
} else if (useDefault) {
   return (defaultValue);
} else {
   throw new ConversionException(stringValue);
}
```

At this point I don’t remember if Struts just logs the exception and fails silently setting false as the value of the parameter or, the exception is propagated (it’s been a while since I used Struts :D but I’m more inclined to think that it just sets false and continues).

The logs should point out the exception even if it is ignored. Setting a logger for `org.apache.commons.beanutils` or `org.apache.struts` should indicate any conversion errors.

Comment: I had some other questions as to why some things were or weren't working, and this answers all of them. Incredibly helpful, thanks a lot.